# Java Loops Hacker Ranker

Tags: java, loops

I'm improving my java programming skills  on hacker rank and I am trying to solve this problem.[Java Loop](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/java-loops).

My input works well with the first ***a***, ***b*** and ***n*** but with second values doesnt work :

2

0 2 10

5 3 5

output:

2  6  14  30  62  126  254  510  1022  2046

8  19  36  65  118

JAVA Code:

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int number =sc.nextInt();

            int loop=1;
            int result=0;
            /*2
            0 2 10
            5 3 5

            2 6 14 30 62 126 254 510 1022 2046
            8 14 26 50 98
            */


            while(loop<=number){
                int a=sc.nextInt();
                int b=sc.nextInt();
                int c=b;
                int n=sc.nextInt();
                result=0;

            for(int x=1;x<=n;x++){

                result=a+(1*b)+result;


                System.out.printf(" "+result +" ");
                b*=2;


            }   


                loop++;
            }



    }

}
```

Comment: 404 on the hacker rank link?

Comment: You might want to expand those `int`s to `long`s; HackerRank really likes to use huge values in the blind test cases

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
static int[] javaLoops(int a, int b, int n) {
    int[] result = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0, k = 1, e = a + k * b; i < n; ++i, k *= 2, e += k * b)
        result[i] = e;
    return result;
}

public void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(javaLoops(0, 2, 10)));
    // -> [2, 6, 14, 30, 62, 126, 254, 510, 1022, 2046]
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(javaLoops(5, 3, 5)));
    // -> [8, 14, 26, 50, 98]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=in.nextInt();
        for(int j=0;j<t;j++){
            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int x=1;
        int temp=a;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            temp+=(x*b);
            System.out.print(temp+" ");
            x*=2;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a again in every iteration of the for(x) loop! It should only be included once per outputted term.

Additionally, your white spacing doesn't appear correct. There'll be a trailing space on each line of output, and there are no new lines between each test case.

This seems to be a valid solution:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaLoops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
        INPUT
        2
        0 2 10
        5 3 5
        OUTPUT
        2 6 14 30 62 126 254 510 1022 2046
        8 14 26 50 98
        */
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t, tc, a, b, c, n, i;
        tc = in.nextInt();
        for (t = 0; t < tc; ++t) {
            a = in.nextInt();
            b = in.nextInt();
            c = 0;
            n = in.nextInt();
            for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                System.out.print(a + c + b);
                c += b;
                b *= 2;
                if (i < n - 1) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loops {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b, n, t,i = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        t = sc.nextInt();

        while(i < t){
            int sum = 0;
            a = sc.nextInt();
            b = sc.nextInt();
            n = sc.nextInt();

            for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                if(k < 1)
                    sum += a + ((int)Math.pow(2, k) * b);
                else
                    sum += ((int)Math.pow(2, k) * b);
                    System.out.printf("%s ",sum);
            }
            System.out.println();
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Solution{
        static void series(int a, int b, int n) {

    for (int i = 0, k = 1, e = a + k * b; i < n; ++i, k *= 2, e += k * b)

        System.out.print(e+" ");

}

public static  void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int t=in.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++) {
         int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        int n = in.nextInt();
    series(a,b,n);
        System.out.println("");
    }



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Solution{
public static void main(String []argh){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=in.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        int pow1 = 0;


        for(int j = 0; j<n;j++){
            pow1 = pow1 + ((int)Math.pow(2,j) * b); 
            sum = a + pow1 ;
            System.out.print(sum + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    in.close();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void EasyJavaLoop2(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=in.nextInt();
    int a =0 , b = 0 , n = 0;
    for(int k=0;k<t;k++){
         a = in.nextInt();
         b = in.nextInt();
         n = in.nextInt();
             int sum = 0;
             int stage = 1;
            sum += a+(stage*b);
            for (int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
                System.out.print(sum + " ");
                stage=stage*2;
                sum += (stage*b);

       }System.out.println("");

    }
    in.close();




}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=in.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
        {
            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int p=a+b;
            int x=1;
            System.out.print(p+" ");
            for(int j=2;j<=n;j++)
            {
                x=x*2;
                p=p+ x*b;   
                 System.out.print(p+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Just dumping code, without providing any context or commentary, does not help students to learn or improve their Java skills.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.